# React hook component is not updated even though state is changed by useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

Long story short I've got a react + redux application with basic logic: `<App />` is the main component in which `useEffect` with no deps is firing requests for the required data (user info, etc) by dispatching actions. Until data is returned simple "Loading" message is shown. The problem is that after those actions are completed and the redux state is changed,  doesn't get re-rendered and "Loading" stays.

```
import {
    Outlet,
    Route,
    Routes
} from 'react-router-dom';

// Screens
import Login from './public/Login';

import './App.module.scss';
import Layout from "../../common/partials/Layout";
import Requests from "./private/Requests";
import Profile from "./private/Profile";
import AuthValidator from "../../common/components/AuthProvider";
import Register from "./public/Register";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUserData } from '../actions/auth';
import Home from "./Home";
import { State } from "../store";
import VerifyEmail from "./public/VerifyEmail";
import { onMobileLayoutSet } from '../../common/actions/layout';
import ProfileWizard from "./private/profile_wizard/ProfileWizardContainer";
import { getMetaData } from "../../common/actions/metadata";

const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {
        auth: { isLogged },
        layout: { isMobile },
        metadata: { countries },
        profile: { profileExists }
    } = useSelector((state: State) => state);

    useEffect( () => {
        dispatch(getUserData());
        dispatch(getMetaData());

        const { innerWidth: width } = window;
        if (width < 1400 && !isMobile) {
            dispatch(onMobileLayoutSet());
        }
    }, []);

    if (isLogged == null || (isLogged && countries.length == 0) || profileExists == null) {
        return (
            <div>Loading</div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path={ "/" } element={ <Home/> }/>
            <Route
                element={ <AuthValidator loginAddress={ '/login' } defaultAddress={ '/requests' } isLogged={ isLogged }><Outlet/></AuthValidator> }>
                <Route element={ <AuthValidator.Block mustBeLogged={ false }><Outlet/></AuthValidator.Block> }>
                    <Route path={ "/login" } element={ <Login/> }/>
                    <Route path={ "/register" } element={ <Register/> }/>
                    <Route path={ "/verify-email" } element={ <VerifyEmail/> }/>
                </Route>
                <Route element={ <AuthValidator.Block mustBeLogged={ true }><Outlet/></AuthValidator.Block> }>
                    <Route element={ <Layout isMobile={ isMobile }><Outlet/></Layout> }>
                        <Route path={ "/requests" } element={ <Requests/> }/>
                        <Route path={ "/profile" } element={ <Profile/> }/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path={ "/profile-wizard" } element={ <ProfileWizard/> }/>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
};

export default App;
```

But when I check both react and redux states they appear to be changed (given one can trust react/redux tools).
React state:

[image: react state]

Redux State:

[image: redux state]

Update:

But if I do the same thing without useEffect, everything works as expected (but looks uglier)

```
// useEffect( () => {
//     dispatch(getUserData());
//     dispatch(getMetaData());
//
//     const { innerWidth: width } = window;
//     if (width < 1400 && !isMobile) {
//         dispatch(onMobileLayoutSet());
//     }
// }, []);

if (isLogged == null && !userDataIsBeingRequested) {
    dispatch(getUserData());
}

if(countries.length === 0 && !metadataRequested) {
    dispatch(getMetaData());
}

const { innerWidth: width } = window;
if (width < 1400 && !isMobile) {
    dispatch(onMobileLayoutSet());
}
```

Update 2:

Sample action creator (I'm using self-implemented api middleware):

```
export const login = ({ email }) => requestAction({
    actionType: 'LOGIN',
    url: '/api/worker/login',
    onRequest: () => {
        return { type: AuthActions.LoginAttempt, email }
    },
    onError: (responseData) => {
        if (responseData.data.error.code === 'UserNotFound') {
            return onLoginError(responseData.data.error.message);
        }
    },
    onSuccess: () => onLoginSuccess(),
    method: RequestMethod.Post,
    data: { email },
});
```

Sample reducer:

```
export enum Actions {
    LoginAttempt = "LoginAttempt",
    LoginError = "LoginError",
    LoginSuccess = "LoginSuccess",
    GetUserDataSuccess = "GetUserDataSuccess",
    GetUserDataFail = "GetUserDataFail",
    GetUserDataAttempt = "GetUserDataAttempt",
    RegisterAttempt = "RegisterAttempt",
    RegisterError = "RegisterError",
    RegisterSuccess = "RegisterSuccess",
    BackToSignUp = "BackToSignUp",
    EmailChanged = "EmailChanged",
    LogoutAttempt = "LogoutAttempt",
    LogoutSuccess = "LogoutSuccess",
    LogoutFail = "LogoutFail",
}

export type AuthState = {
    passwordSent: boolean,
    isLogged: boolean | null,
    isLoading: boolean,
    userId: string | null,
    firstName: string | null,
    lastName: string | null,
    number: number | null,
    email: string | null,
    userDataIsBeingRequested: boolean,
    registrationComplete: boolean
    loginComplete: boolean
    emailErrorMessage: string | null
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
    passwordSent: false,
    isLogged: null,
    isLoading: false,
    registrationComplete: false,
    userId: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    number: null,
    email: null,
    userDataIsBeingRequested: false,
    emailErrorMessage: null,
    loginComplete: false
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.GetUserDataSuccess: {
            return { ...state, ...action.userInfo, isLogged: action.isLogged, userDataIsBeingRequested: false };
        }
        case Actions.GetUserDataFail: {
            return { ...state, isLogged: false, userDataIsBeingRequested: false };
        }
        case Actions.GetUserDataAttempt: {
            return { ...state, userDataIsBeingRequested: true };
        }
        case Actions.RegisterAttempt: {
            return {...state, isLoading: true, email: action.email};
        }
        case Actions.RegisterSuccess: {
            return {...state, isLoading: false, registrationComplete: true};
        }
        case Actions.BackToSignUp: {
            return {...state, email: null};
        }
        case Actions.RegisterError: {
            return {...state, emailErrorMessage: action.emailErrorMessage, isLoading: false}
        }
        case Actions.EmailChanged: {
            return {...state, emailErrorMessage: null}
        }
        case Actions.LoginAttempt: {
            return {...state, isLoading: true}
        }
        case Actions.LoginError: {
            return {...state, emailErrorMessage: action.emailErrorMessage, isLoading: false}
        }
        case Actions.LoginSuccess: {
            return {...state, loginComplete: true, isLoading: false}
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default authReducer;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your dependency array is empty.

Comment: Yeah, I need those requests to fire only once (which they do). The problem is that after the state is updated and component is to be re-rendered (so that Routes are shown), but that's not happening.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems in the code that you've shared. What do your action creators and reducers look like?

Comment: @JoshKelley Well, seems like example without useEffect must isolate the problem, but updated my question anyway

Comment: This is really weird.  Usually it's a lot more obvious where the problem is but I'm not seeing it.  I wonder if the three actions are interfering with each other.  I would definitely throw some `console.log`s in before the `if` statement.  `console.log({ isLogged, countries.length, profileExists})` `console.log(isLogged == null || (isLogged && countries.length == 0) || profileExists == null)`

Comment: It's not a great practice to select the whole state in the `useSelector` as it will cause you component to re-render when any part of state changes (not just the parts that you care about).  But that's more of a performance thing and should not cause this sort of problem.

Comment: Logging was the first thing I did. Component is not updating hence there is only 1 log in console with the initial values.